# Dynamically allocating two dimensional string array and passing it as parameter to functions

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

This is the code. It is supposed to read text from the user and then separate that text to paragraphs, sentences and words. I am stuck on the paragraphs phase as I seem to be able to get the code working only if I input text once. The second time I try to input text I get a segmentation faulted (core dumped) error. I think it has something to do with the `realloc` in the function but I am not sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void read_par(char ***p, char ***s, char ***w, int *n_p, int *n_s, int *n_w)
{
    char *temp = malloc(10001 * sizeof(char));

    fgets(temp, 10001, stdin);
    //paragraphs
    *n_p += 1;
    **p = realloc(**p, *n_p * sizeof(char *));
    *p[*n_p - 1] = malloc((strlen(temp) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(*p[*n_p - 1], temp);

}

int main()
{
    char option[4], **paragraphs = malloc(sizeof(char *)), **sentences = malloc(sizeof(char *)), **words = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    int num_par = 0, num_sent = 0, num_words = 0, i;

    fgets(option, 4, stdin);
    option[strcspn(option, "\n")] = '\0';

    while(strcmp(option, "qt"))
    {
        if(!(strcmp(option, "ap")))
            read_par(&paragraphs, &sentences, &words, &num_par, &num_sent, &num_words);

        fgets(option, 4, stdin);
        option[strcspn(option, "\n")] = '\0';
    }

    for(i = 0;i < num_par;i++)
        printf("%s", paragraphs[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In all your `char **` variables you are each time allocating only room for _one_ pointer. Is that what you intend?

Comment: Oh...I see you realloc. But then `num_par = 0` should be 1 because you had allocated one alreay.

Comment: Maybe you should work on your task progressively, instead of trying to do everything at once. First, try saving all words into a char* variable, after you complete that try saving each sentence in a char** variable etc... Currently there are many mistakes (to me) and missing things in your code I don't know where to start fixing.

Comment: I change the value of the num_par within the function for every paragraph read. It works fine when it allocates memory for the *p[0] but it crashes on the *p[1] for some reason. I gave up on trying to get it to work like this i just declared a static array of 1000 pointers, it will probably get the job done.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the return of malloc and realloc in case they fail.
The call to realloc needs one de-reference `*p`. It is a good practice to assign realloc to a temporary pointer in case of failure. The original pointer is still valid.
In the function, using `char line[10001]` avoids malloc and free. The absence of free in the original code, leaks memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void read_par(char ***p, char ***s, char ***w, int *n_p, int *n_s, int *n_w)
{
    char line[10001] = "";
    char **tmp = NULL;//tmp pointer for realloc

    printf ( "\tenter line\n");
    fgets ( line, 10001, stdin);
    //paragraphs
    *n_p += 1;
    if ( NULL != ( tmp = realloc ( *p, *n_p * sizeof(char *)))) {
        if ( NULL != ( tmp[*n_p - 1] = malloc ( ( strlen ( line) + 1) * sizeof(char)))) {
            strcpy ( tmp[*n_p - 1], line);
            *p = tmp;//assign tmp pointer to *p
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "malloc problem\n");
            *p = tmp;
            *n_p -= 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        fprintf ( stderr, "realloc problem\n");
        *n_p -= 1;
    }

}

int main( void)
{
    char option[4], **paragraphs = NULL, **sentences = NULL, **words = NULL;
    int num_par = 0, num_sent = 0, num_words = 0, i;


    do {
        printf ( "\nenter option:");
        fflush ( stdout);
        fgets ( option, 4, stdin);
        option[strcspn ( option, "\n")] = '\0';
        if( ! ( strcmp ( option, "ap")))
            read_par ( &paragraphs, &sentences, &words, &num_par, &num_sent, &num_words);

    } while ( strcmp ( option, "qt"));

    for( i = 0; i < num_par; i++)
        printf ( "%s", paragraphs[i]);

    for ( i = 0; i < num_par; i++)
        free ( paragraphs[i]);

    free(paragraphs);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding the string something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t nstrings;
    char *strings[];
}myStringTable_t;

myStringTable_t *init(void)
{
    return calloc(sizeof(myStringTable_t),1);
}

char *addString(const char *str, myStringTable_t **mst)
{
    myStringTable_t *mst_temp;
    char *temp;

    if(mst && *mst && str)
    {
        temp = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
        if(temp)
        {
            mst_temp = realloc(*mst, sizeof(*mst) + ((*mst) -> nstrings + 1) * sizeof(*(*mst) -> strings));
            if(mst_temp)
            {
                *mst = mst_temp;
                strcpy(temp, str);
                (*mst) -> strings[(*mst) -> nstrings++] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                free(temp);
                temp = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: This is a bit too advanced for me.

Comment: It is more simple than yours :)

Comment: If feel these to names `myStringTable_t **mst` and `myStringTable_t *mst_temp` are confusing. They do not go together very well.